# Porqué no me deja poner un gif transparente en un tk?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

He estado intenado hace mucho poner un gif circular dentro de un tk que tiene una imagen de fondo, pero cada vez que lo hago me aparece con relleno de color blanco por el canvas.

Intenté probar con labeles, canvas, frames pero nada, me sigue apareciendo con relleno y cuadrado, y ya me asegure de que el gif tenga transparencia.

La imagen png circular es "myimg" pero no logro hacer que tenga transparencia, y con eso me refiero a que solo se vea el circulo, no el relleno del canvas ni nada, ayuda porfa :(

Así es como me sale [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Pero quiero que solo aparesca la pelotita roja

intenté ponerlo en un frame pero me sale así
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import tkinter as tk


ventana=tk.Tk()
ventana.title("Bosque")
ventana.geometry('900x800')
ventana.resizable(0,0)


image=tk.PhotoImage(file="labetinto.gif")
image=image.subsample(1,1)
lab=tk.Label(image=image)
lab.pack()
lab.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1.0,relheight=1.0)

canvas = tk.Canvas(ventana)
canvas.pack()

myimg = tk.PhotoImage(file='circlo.png')
canvas.create_image(100,100,image=myimg)

boton = tk.Button(ventana,text="  ",font=("Verdana",17))
boton.config(bg="#135C3F", fg="#D7D731")
boton.place(x=750,y=326)

boton1 = tk.Button(ventana,text="  ",font=("Verdana",17))
boton1.config(bg="#135C3F", fg="#D7D731")
boton1.place(x=750,y=426)

boton2 = tk.Button(ventana,text=" Ir ",font=("Verdana",17))
boton2.config(bg="#135C3F", fg="#D7D731")
boton2.place(x=750,y=376)

boton3 = tk.Button(ventana,text="  ",font=("Verdana",17))
boton3.config(bg="#135C3F", fg="#D7D731")
boton3.place(x=808,y=376)

boton4 = tk.Button(ventana,text="  ",font=("Verdana",17))
boton4.config(bg="#135C3F", fg="#D7D731")
boton4.place(x=691,y=376)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

LO LOGRÉ PORFIN :'D

Lo que pasa es que la imagen de fondo que puse al principio se interponía en lo demás, supongo que porque el label tapaba o no sé
Puse el fondo en el mismo canvas donde puse el png transparente y lo logré :)

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image


ventana=tk.Tk()
ventana.title("Bosque")
ventana.geometry('900x800')
ventana.resizable(0,0)


frame = tk.Frame(ventana)
frame.pack()

canvas = tk.Canvas(frame, width=900, height=800)
canvas.pack()

image=tk.PhotoImage(file="labetinto.gif")
canvas.create_image(450,400,image=image)

myimg = tk.PhotoImage(file='circlo.png')
canvas.create_image(70,235,image=myimg)


boton = tk.Button(ventana,text="  ",font=("Verdana",17))
boton.config(bg="#135C3F", fg="#D7D731")
boton.place(x=750,y=326)

boton1 = tk.Button(ventana,text="  ",font=("Verdana",17))
boton1.config(bg="#135C3F", fg="#D7D731")
boton1.place(x=750,y=426)

boton2 = tk.Button(ventana,text=" Ir ",font=("Verdana",17))
boton2.config(bg="#135C3F", fg="#D7D731")
boton2.place(x=750,y=376)

boton3 = tk.Button(ventana,text="  ",font=("Verdana",17))
boton3.config(bg="#135C3F", fg="#D7D731")
boton3.place(x=808,y=376)

boton4 = tk.Button(ventana,text="  ",font=("Verdana",17))
boton4.config(bg="#135C3F", fg="#D7D731")
boton4.place(x=691,y=376)

ventana.mainloop()
```